# How to reorder categories in TCategoryPanelGroup (Delphi XE)

Tags: delphi

I have a TCategoryPanelGroup instance dropped on a form. I would like to allow the user to reorder the categories. In tryed to reorder Panels[] property - which is a TList - but this doesn't seems to work.

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you want users to be able to reorder them via mouse dragging or via some other technique?  If you want to see a code example of mouse-down based drag and drop reordering, check out CategoryButtons.pas in the VCL source code for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Effect this change by modifying the position of the panels:

```
CategoryPanel2.Top := 0;
CategoryPanel1.Top := CategoryPanel2.Height;
```

Comment: Thanks. Setting the top value of an existing panel will move it just above the existing panel. Setting top value one more of existing panel will move the panel below the existing.