# TabOrder of TCategoryPanel into TCategoryPanelGroup

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to add new TCategoryPanel in a TCategoryPanelGroup but I can not order the TabOrder panels. My code is like this:

```
function AddPanel (_AName, _ACaption: string): TCategoryPanel;
var
  ACategoryPanel: TCategoryPanel;

   ACategoryPanel: = TCategoryPanel (CategoryPanelGroup.CreatePanel (CategoryPanelGroup));
   ACategoryPanel.Name: = _AName;
   ACategoryPanel.Caption: = _ACaption;
   ACategoryPanel.Top: = 1000;

   Result: = ACategoryPanel;
end;
```

I call this code many times to add some panels. I tryed to set the Top property with a high value after reading this topic: [Order of TCategoryPanel into TCategoryPanelGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397488/order-of-tcategorypanel-into-tcategorypanelgroup)

But this only corrects the visible order of the panels I guess, and my problem is with the TabOrder.

I did this test:

```
  ACategory1 := AddPanel ('Category1', 'Category 1');
  ACategory2 := AddPanel ('Category2', 'Category 2');
  ACategory3 := AddPanel ('Category3', 'Category 3');
```

In the screen, the order will be:

```
  Category1
  Category2
  Category3
```

But the TabOrder will be:

```
  Category1 = 2
  Category2 = 1
  Category3 = 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got what I wanted creating a inherited class from TCategoryPanelGroup:

```
TOrderedCategoryPanelGroup = class(TCategoryPanelGroup)
public
  procedure ReorderTabOrderByList;
end;

procedure TOrderedCategoryPanelGroup.ReorderTabOrderByList;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Panels.Count - 1 do
  begin
    TWinControl(Panels[i]).TabOrder := i;
  end;
end;
```

Using this way:

```
procedure ProcessPanelGroup(CategoryPanelGroup: TOrderedCategoryPanelGroup);
begin
  CreatePanels(CategoryPanelGroup); //Create the PanelGroups
  CategoryPanelGroup.ReorderTabOrderByList;
end;
```

The responsibility of maintaining the ordering of the panels is from his parent, as it should be. I do not want to control something that will only give me more work. This way I can "set the tab order without setting the tab order".

Maybe this could be done also inheriting the TCategoryPanelGroup.CreatePanel method. That way I will not need to call the sorting out of the object.

Comment: I think you need a blog to publish this stuff

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `TabOrder`. For instance:

```
ACategory1.TabOrder := 0;
ACategory2.TabOrder := 1;
ACategory3.TabOrder := 2;
```

Comment: Thank you David, but I haven't the instances, I create them dynamically. The user can create as many as he wants

Comment: You do have the instances when you create them. Indeed in the code snippets in the question, the instances can clearly be seen. So, you are quite mistaken when you think that you don't have the instances. You could do set the `TabOrder` of each new panel to be `CategoryPanelGroup.ControlCount-1`. Or you could keep track of the latest `TabOrder` that you have set. All the same, I cannot believe that you think you can set the tab order without setting the tab order.

Comment: Of course I have the instance, I don't have a variable with the reference to the instance, was just an example. To fix it I was using a external list and setting the TabOrder all the time a Panel is added, but the CategoryPanelGroup.ControlCount-1 looks me better. Thanks